# Make changes to a .cs file using powershell

Tags: c#, powershell, replace

I'm trying to make some replacements in a .cs file using PowerShell.
For example I have:

`string MyFunction (string param1 = null, int? param2 = null)` which I need to be cyhanged to:
`string MyFunction (byte[] _file = null, string param1 = null, int? param2 = null)`

Right now the part of the code to make this change looks like:
`$target = "Path\File.cs"
(Get-Content $target) -replace "MyFunction (string param1 = null, int? param2 = null)", "MyFunction (byte[] _file = null, string param1 = null, int? param2 = null)"| Set-Content $target`

The code opens the file (Some other changes in it work) but it does not make any changes to my function
I have tried to put a "\" in front of the parenthesis, to use the -Raw command when getting the content of the file and something like this:
`(Get-Content $target) | ForEach-Object { $_ -replace "MyFunction (string param1 = null, int? param2 = null)", "MyFunction (byte[] _file = null, string param1 = null, int? param2 = null)" } | Set-Content $target`

On the same file I also have another modification from: 
`string MyFunction2(param1);`
to 
`string MyFunction2(_file, param1);` 
This replace worked when I used: 
`(Get-Content $target) -replace "MyFunction2\(param1\);", "MyFunction2(_file, param1);"| Set-Content $target`

How chould I write the PowerShell code to make the changes?

Answer (score 2):

`-replace` is a regex operator, and you need to escape your input to match it as-is - otherwise the regex engine will interpret `(`, `)` and `?` as control characters:

```
$replaceEscaped = [regex]::Escape('string MyFunction (string param1 = null, int? param2 = null)')
$substitute = 'string MyFunction (byte[] _file = null, string param1 = null, int? param2 = null)'

(Get-Content $target) -replace $replaceEscaped, $substitute
```

Check out the [`about_Regular_Expressions` help document](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.core/about/about_regular_expressions#escaping-characters) for more on how to escape patterns

Comment: I missed the escape on the question mark, it worked after I added it, Thanks